# How to say grammatically "something which if it matters.."?

Tags: grammar

I'd like to say things in this way, is it proper? For example

> He went to see her which I don't know if was the the right thing to do..

Is it right? If false what makes it so? How can I express the same thing the most conscience way?

Thank you..

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear.  Can you add a little context and explain what specific aspect you're questioning?

Comment: I think *which* is out of place. I am not sure what you are trying to say, but maybe "He went to see her.  I don't know if *it* was the the right thing to do.. " or "He went to see her *though* I don't know if *it* was the the right thing to do.. "

Comment: the question here is how can I use "which, if and it" all n harmony to make things grammatically correct..

Answer (score 2):

The phrase could make sense, but it is lacking punctuation, and has a few grammatical errors.

It would be, "He went to see her, but I don't know if it was the right thing to do."

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there any way to say it the way I constructed? because I dont know why we have to use "but" instead of which, but adds some negativity (kind of) hence I want to make it more neutral sounding by using "which" he went to see her whether which was the right thing to do I don't know. OR like in original, he went to see her which I don't know if was the right thing to do..

Answer (score 1):

Trying to stay close to the syntax of your original statement:

> He went to see her, which *I am not sure* was the right thing to do.
>
> He went to see her, which was the right thing to do.
>
> He went to see her, which was the wrong thing to do.
>
> He went to see her, which *I am uncertain* was the right thing to do.

The phrase "I don't know *if*..." must be followed by a clause with a subject:

> ... I don't know if **it** was the right thing to do.

However, you have chosen to use the relative **which**, and a *which*-clause must not use the pronoun **it** to refer back to the subject in the main clause:

> He went to see her, **which** I don't know if **it** was the right thing to do.  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

If you want to use **it**, you must abandon the *which*-clause and use a conjunction instead:

> He went to see her **but** I don't know if *it* was the right thing to do.

P.S. The blah-blah, which I am not sure if I like it  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

The antecedent of **which** is the nominal "blah-blah".

*I am not sure* wants as its complement an independent clause:

> I am not sure *I like it*.
>
> I am not sure if I like it <sup>marginal / ungrammatical</sup>
>
> I don't know if|whether I like it.

Comment: I like your progressive reasoning, is there any way to say it the way I constructed? because I dont know why we have to use "but" instead of which, but adds some negativity (kind of) hence I want to make it more neutral sounding by using "which"  he went to see her whether which was the right thing to do I don't know. OR like in original, he went to see her which I don't know if was the right thing to do..

Comment: You want to express the idea that you have reservations about his action. You can either use a conjunction that expresses the idea [but, though, although, yet, however] or you can use a modal. Conjunction: *He went to see her, **though** I'm not sure it was the right thing to do.* Modal: *He went  to see her, which **may not have been** the right thing to do.*

Comment: You can also say *He went to see her, which, I'm uncertain, was the right thing to do.*  [that is, without repeating **it** in the relative clause, which is disallowed, as  **which** is the subject of **was**.  I've added commas around "I'm uncertain" to try to indicate its syntactic role in the clause. It is a predication about the predication in the relative clause in which it is embedded as an aside.]

Comment: I think the tough example misses "if/whether" right? He went to see her, tough I'm not sure if/whether it was the right thing to do..?? secondly, my answer in question is then correct if I omit "if"? you gave same example without if and using "I'm uncertain" instead of "I don't know" right? also thirdly and finally, the point of this question is why can I not use "if" to say bla bla.. which I'm not sure if I like it.. why do we have to omit the "if" here? thank you

Comment: You can say, "...which I'm not sure I like", using relative **which** as the  object of **like**.  In a *which*-clause, you cannot use a pronoun to refer back to the antecedent of **which** in the matrix clause.    *The book, which I gave **it** to you, had a red cover.* [ungrammatical]. *The book, which I'm not sure if I like **it**, had a red cover.* [ungrammatical].  Removing **it** for that reason, we're left with  "which I'm not sure if I like" which lacks an object for **like** in the *if*-clause complement of **sure**, and is ungrammatical for that reason.

Comment: And "I'm not sure" wants as its complement an independent clause not an *if*-clause.

Comment: so grammatically correct one is? "...which I'm not sure was the right thing"? the other correct form being  "..though I'm not sure if it was the right thing"?

Comment: also why not "which I'm not sure if I like"? here because we have "which" we don't need "it". also don't we like automatically "which"? so we don't need "it" because we like the "which"?

Comment: You are nesting a clause within an already nested clause here.